# Strange behavior of 'saveAsTextFile' method

Tags: apache-spark

I have such code:

```
val relationships: RDD[String] = ....
relationships.saveAsTextFile("/tmp/result")
```

I expected that 'saveAsTextFile' method saves 'relationships' to file '/tmp/result'.
But it created folder '/tmp/result/' and put there a lot of text files with names part-00000, part-00001, etc. 
Is it normal behavior of this method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that it saves it as multiple files because the computation is distributed.

If you require the file to be saved with saveAsTextFile you can use
 `coalesce(1,true).saveAsTextFile();`.

This basically means to do the computation and then coalesce it into 1 partition. You can also use `repartition(1)`, which is just a wrapper for `coalesce()` with the suffle argument set to true.

As an alternative, if your data fit in one partition you can collect your rdd and then save the array.

Comment: Note than when working with big output sizes, the saving performance will be worse as you redirect all the data into a single partition.

Answer (score 0):

That's not strange, As Tim said that's exepected behaviou because the computation is distributed.

I just want to add that if your RDD is too big, running coalesce might not be a great idea